# filter array link node

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm new react developer, here i'm using 'react-d3-graph' to get my nodes and links, at the moment using 'info' i'm successfully getting 3 nodes and two links, those links connect to nodes. for example link with 'target:1' is connected to node 'id:1' and link with 'target:2' is connected to node 'id:2' (links and nodes could be many more than this). My question is, is there a way to filter this, if user clicks a button then from redux i'm getting 'testThis' object, that object shows currently clicked buttons 'identifier' and that identifier can be in those 'nodes' with the name of 'book_id', how to filter it, so that if 'nodes' contain 'book_id' which value is same as 'identifier' value then find it and select it. In this case it should select  node which has book_id and its link with it(link with target 2) so with that user only can see two nodes and one link, is this possible ? so then Graph would be getting this :
after button clicked:

```js
{
  links: [
    {
      id: 1,
      source: 0,
      target: 2,
      color: 'green',
    },
  ],
  nodes: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Camera',
      x: 210,
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      book_id: 'gDUy',
      id: 2,
      name: 'livingRoom',
      x: 400,
      y: 210,
    },
  ],
};
```

before button clicked:

```js
import { Graph } from 'react-d3-graph';

const testThis ={
    identifier: "gDUy",
}


const info = {
  links: [
    {
      id: 0,
      source: 0,
      target: 1,
      color: 'green',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      source: 0,
      target: 2,
      color: 'green',
    },
  ],
  nodes: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Camera',
      x: 210,
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Kitchen',
      x: 0,
      y: 210,
    },
    {
      book_id: 'gDUy',
      id: 2,
      name: 'livingRoom',
      x: 400,
      y: 210,
    },
  ],
};


  <Graph
          data={info}

        />
```

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const testThis = {
  identifier: "gDUy",
}


const info = {
  links: [{
      id: 0,
      source: 0,
      target: 1,
      color: 'green',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      source: 0,
      target: 2,
      color: 'green',
    },
  ],
  nodes: [{
      id: 0,
      name: 'Camera',
      x: 210,
      y: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Kitchen',
      x: 0,
      y: 210,
    },
    {
      book_id: 'gDUy',
      id: 2,
      name: 'livingRoom',
      x: 400,
      y: 210,
    },
  ],
};

function filterGraph() {
  let nodes = info.nodes.filter(x => x.book_id == testThis.identifier);
  let links = info.links.filter(x => nodes.map(y => y.id).includes(x.target));
  let sourceNodes = info.nodes.filter(x => links.map(y => y.source).includes(x.id));
  let allNodes = nodes.concat(sourceNodes);
  console.log({links:links,nodes:allNodes});
}

filterGraph();
```

Comment: Check the edits I made